# Layout XML block rendered twice in Magento skin

Tags: xml

I'm having a bit of trouble with a custom layout block which I'm trying to add to the *head.phtml* file of my theme. Basically, I'm trying to add extra favicon definitions to the header of my document.

In my local.xml file, I've added the lines:

```
<default>
    <reference name="head">
        <block type="core/template" name="favicon.extra" as="favicon.extra" template="page/html/head/favicon-extra.phtml" />
    </reference>
</default>
```

And then inside *head.phtml*, I'm calling this as a *childHtml* template as:

```
<link rel="icon" href="<?php echo $this->getFaviconFile(); ?>" type="image/x-icon" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="<?php echo $this->getFaviconFile(); ?>" type="image/x-icon" />
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('favicon.extra') ?>
```

The problem is that the block is rendered twice, in two different spots:

1. Underneath the other favicons, as per the *head.phtml* getChildHtml call, and
2. After the other scripts in the header

The desired outcome is that I **only want the first of these two to render**.

From what I've read, I think this has to do with that particular block/reference being automatically rendered via the toHtml output - is this correct?

If so, is there a better/correct way to accomplish what I'm trying to do here? Is there another way to **remove the second render**?

Any help possible is much appreciated.

Comment: What happens if you remove the call from `head.phtml`? Do the extra icons still work with just the second render?

Comment: @clockworkgeek - I believe they do, but the output is quite messy and not ideal. It does partially solve the problem at hand, but if possible I'd like to understand how to remove the second render rather than the first.

Comment: @Marius : That is what I mentioned in my answer. Not aware of the above mentioned question

Answer (score 2):

You are included your templte block inside `head` block. `head` block will render its child blocks automatically. That means, you don't want to call your block again in your `head.phtml` file. So remove that part from your template. Means you need to remove this part.

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('favicon.extra') ?>
```

It will make your block render only once

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to remove the xml code from  `local.xml`  and instead of

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('favicon.extra') ?>
```

in the `header.phtml` , use following code:

```
<?php  echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('core/template')->setTemplate('page/html/head/favicon-extra.phtml'); ?>
```

Comment: This is wrong, it will disable block caching